# numpy ravel versus flat in slice assignment

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

According to the documentation, [`ndarray.flat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html) is an iterator over the array while [`ndarray.ravel`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html) returns a flattened array (when possible). So my question is, when should we use one or the other?
Which one would be preferred as the rvalue in an assignment like the one in the code below?

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(2).reshape((2,1,1))
y = np.arange(3).reshape((1,3,1))
z = np.arange(5).reshape((1,1,5))

mask = np.random.choice([True, False], size=(2,3,5))
# netCDF4 module wants this kind of boolean indexing:
nc4slice = tuple(mask.any(axis=axis) for axis in ((1,2),(2,0),(0,1)))
indices = np.ix_(*nc4slice)

ncrds = 3
npnts = (np.broadcast(*indices)).size
points = np.empty((npnts, ncrds))
for i,crd in enumerate(np.broadcast_arrays(x,y,z)):
    # Should we use ndarray.flat ...
    points[:,i] = crd[indices].flat
    # ... or ndarray.ravel():
    points[:,i] = crd[indices].ravel()
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need either. `crd[mask]` is already 1-d. If you did, numpy always calls `np.asarray(rhs)` first, so it is the same if no copy is needed for `ravel`. When the copy is needed, I would guess that `ravel` may be faster currently (I did not time it).

If you knew that a copy might be needed, and here you know that *nothing* is needed, reshaping `points` could actually be the fastest. Since you usually don't need the fastest, I would say it is more a matter of taste, and would personally probably use `ravel`.

Comment: I updated the sample code to provide an example closer to the real case that originated the question. I do not understand the line about `asarray`. I do know that the result is the same. Actually my question is what does numpy do (behind the scenes) in the above code when using `flat` and when using `ravel`?

Comment: That is what I said, it calls `np.asarray` (effectively) on the right hand side behind the scenes, which means that the `arr.flat` is converted to an array anyway. It still doesn't matter which one you use.

Comment: Ok, so my last question should have been: assuming that `asarray` method does nothing when input is already an array, what does `asarray` do when the input is an iterator? [Documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html) says nothing about array iterators.